# update angular button after kinetics animation is finished

Tags: angularjs, kineticjs

I've created video player with kinetics canvas. after click on play button kinetics animation starts and the button changes to pause. I would like to have play button again after the animations is finished. 
here is the code:

angular:

```
    $scope.isPreviewPlaying = function(){
       return preview != null && preview.isRunning();
    }
    $scope.playPreview = function(){
         .....
         preview.stop;
    }
    $scope.pausePreview = function(){
      preview.stop();
    }
```

html:

```
    <button ng-click="playPreview()" ng-show="!isPreviewPlaying()">

    <button ng-click="pausePreview()" ng-show="isPreviewPlaying()">
```

Comment: Try using `$watch` on the function `review.isRunning`

Answer (score 0):

So I'm assuming you're using a `Kinetic.Tween` right instead of a `Kinetic.Animation`?

The difference is that a tween is a fire and forget animation that has a start and an endpoint (sounds like what you have) and the animation is an animation that runs in a loop.

You can use the `onFinish` event property of a `Kinetic.Tween` to run whatever angularJS code you need to switch the Pause button back to the Play button:

```
var rect = new Kinetic.Rect({
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  width: 100,
  height: 50,
  fill: 'green',
  stroke: 'black',
  strokeWidth: 2,
  opacity: 0.2
}); 

var tween = new Kinetic.Tween({
  node: rect, 
  duration: 1,
  x: 400,
  y: 30,
  rotation: Math.PI * 2,
  opacity: 1,
  strokeWidth: 6,
  scaleX: 1.5,
  onFinish: function() {
    //AngularJS Code to set button here.
  }
});
```

Comment: I need Animation because of loopings in some cases and different fps during playback

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by extracting the variable for playBack - $scope.previewPlaying and set it with $scope.$apply inside my Animation.

another problem was that after finishing of video I needed to stop the animation inside the Animation function and it doesn't work. so I used $scope.$watch as proposed by Miszy and the code looks like this:

```
          var preview;
          $scope.previewPlaying = false;

          $scope.playPreview = function(){
             ........
             preview = new Kinetic.Animation(function(frame) {
               if(condition) {
                    $scope.$apply(function() {
                            $scope.previewPlaying = false;
                    })
              }
            )}
         }
         $scope.$watch('previewPlaying', function() {
             if(!$scope.previewPlaying) {
               preview.stop();
             }
         })

       <button ng-click="playPreview()" ng-show="!previewPlaying">

       <button ng-click="pausePreview()" ng-show="previewPlaying">
```